# Full screen dialog close display previous screen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fullscreen

I am implementing code to display full screen dialog on error.

Sequence like Activity A(launch) **->** Activity B(Launch Error Dialog) **->** Full Screen Error Dialog(onBack) **->** Close Activity B and display Activity A.

and here is the problem, before display to Activity A it show glimpse of Activity B, is there any way to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

finish the activity B and then show your full screen error dialog on activity A

Before showing the full screen dialog close activity B. Show you error dialog from Activity A (using some condition, like pass a value from B to A that error dialog needs to be shown and you can use onActivityResult method for this purpose) not B.

Use something like this.

Activity A -> Activity B -> (if error dialog needs to be shown then) close B and send a value to A which would tell that a error dialog needs to be shown --> show error dialog --> press back and you wont see Activity B

Comment: Check your question. You said you want to close Activity B and show A; Now you are saying you don't want to show A. its confusing

Comment: Ohh That was typo, wanted to show Activity A directly from Dialog closing.

Comment: Thats what I told you. Before showing the full screen dialog close activity B. Show you error dialog from Activity A (using some condition, like pass a value from B to A that error dialog needs to be shown and you can use onActivityResult method for this purpose) not B.

Comment: Dear then it will display Activity B and will display Dialog. It just I do not want to show Screen back from which error occur.

Comment: it's same Rohit, since Activity A already open, hence it will display first for millisecond and launch Dialog then.

Answer (score 0):

You can again start intent :
 startActivity(new intent(this, first.class));

Comment: Harsh, I am doing it from Activity-B which is obvious choice to finish Activity B and display Activity A then. But here it show Activity-B for millisecond then Activity A. Any other suggestion!